# The align attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use CSS instead

Tags: html, css

```
<img align="left" src="Logo_CSA.jpg" alt="CSA Logo">
```

How can I remove this problem in img-tag? I am facing this problem when I'm checking my code in w3c validater pls suggest me a best alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: [CSA logo is very poor alt text](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

Answer (score 4):

The `align` [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/index/attributes.html) for `img` was deprecated in 1998. The CSS equivalent is [the `float` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: True, align isn't a supported attribute for img in HTML5 anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Answer (score 0):

Replace align with style:

```
<img style="float: left;" src="Logo_CSA.jpg" alt="CSA Logo">
```